# Checking if the .csv file is formatted correctly before importing to avoid embedding wrong data into database

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I am working on a django project that requires updating database with bulk data provided in an excelsheet format.
So basically, a user can upload a .csv file if it is in a correct format (by correct format i mean, well-formed file with data i expect). I know how to import a file using django-import-export, but the problem is , i don't know how to perform checks like checking if the .csv file has correct column names and information before updating database.
I am new to django, please help.

Comment: What do you define as correct ? Is a well-formed file with data you did not expect correct ? If a single line is malformed but otherwise the file is as expected, do you want to raise for the entire file or ignore the single line ?

Comment: A well-formed file with data i expect is a correct file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Checking for a well formed file

If you are programmatically importing a file, then if you can [load a Dataset object](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/#importing-data), without any errors being raised, then it is a well-formed csv file.  So something like:

```py
import tablib
try:
  with open('data.csv', 'r') as fh:
    imported_data = tablib.Dataset().load(fh, headers=False)
except Exception as e:
  # you can add additional error handling / logging here if you like
  print("import fail")
  raise e
```

#### Checking for correct headers

Before the import process, there is [a hook](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html#import_export.resources.Resource.before_import) you can use to check for valid headers.  So you could do something like the following to check for missing columns:

```py
class YourResource(resources.ModelResource):
    fields = ('author', 'email')

    def before_import(self, dataset, using_transactions, dry_run, **kwargs):
        for field_name in self.fields:
            col_name = self.fields[field_name].column_name
            if col_name not in dataset.headers:
                raise ValueError(f"'{col_name}' field not in data file")
```

#### Data Validation

You can use the in-built [widgets](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_widgets.html) to supply additional validation at the field level.  You can extend these as much as you like to enable additional domain-specific validation.  For example, if you only want to allow '1' or 0' as your boolean values, you could implement the following:

```py
class StrictBooleanWidget(widgets.BooleanWidget):
    TRUE_VALUES = ["1"]
    FALSE_VALUES = ["0"]
    NULL_VALUES = [""]

    def clean(self, value, row=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if value in self.NULL_VALUES:
            return None
        if value in self.TRUE_VALUES:
            return True
        if value in self.FALSE_VALUES:
            return False
        raise ValueError("Invalid boolean: value must be 1 or 0.")
```

Then refer to this in your resource:

```py
class YourResource(resources.ModelResource):
    is_active = fields.Field(
        attribute="active",
        column_name="active",
        default=False,
        widget=upload.widgets.StrictBooleanWidget(),
    )
```

You can also use this approach to check for missing or empty values in the data.

`django-import-export` really helps a lot with the use-case you describe, but it can be confusing when you are new to it.  Read the documentation in depth, and I suggest to download and run the [example application](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#example-app) (if you haven't already).

The core import logic is fairly straightforward, but it will save a ton of time if you can set breakpoints and step through during dev.  That will really help you to understand what is going on.